# Read PHP files using PHP?

Tags: php, html, file-handling

I have a PHP file. I want to read the PHP code written inside that file. The script I am executing is in the file 'test.php'.

```
<?php
$test = file_get_contents('test.php');
echo '<pre>'.$test.'</pre>';
?>
```

The output in browser window is:

```
'.$test.'

'; ?>
```

another test on the file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Canvas Home</title>

  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="http://localhost/collaborate/icons/collaborate.ico">
<?php
    echo "<link rel=\"stylesheet\" type=\"text/css\" href=\"stylesheets/".basename(__FILE__,'.php').".css\">";
    echo "<script type=\"text/javascript\" src=\"js/".basename(__FILE__,'.php').".js\"></script>";
?>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheets/navs.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div></div>
</body>

</html>
```

gave the output:

```
"; echo ""; ?>
```

Can someone explain me what is happening in the first file? I expected the returned string to be simply echoed.

Also in the second file, the first simple HTML part is echoed and hence gets interpreted as HTML, understood. But what happens then? Why is the echo command itself displayed?

I basically want to achieve reading the source of any script file rather than it being executed, i want it displayed in the browser window.

Comment: Use your browser's view source feature (Ctrl+U or so)

Comment: Do you want to read contents of the file, or include it?

Comment: a side remark : be VERY carefull with what you'll be displaying, and to whom. You're basically opening a window on your source code, that's never a good idea and should be used for very specific cases...

Comment: @johannes i would not have asked this question if i wanted to view the source, and I am not trying to view some kind of server side script source of any website. I just want to read the html, or any other script on my local system, through php ofcourse in this context

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you're outputting the raw PHP code to the browser, the browser is trying to render `<?php` as an HTML tag. You'll probably want to run the code through htmlspecial chars so any HTML metacharacters in the PHP code are sent encoded, and then NOT rendered by the browser. e.g.

```
$code = file_get_contents('script.php');
echo '<pre>', htmlspecialchars($code), '</pre>';
```

And note that your browser LIES to you about output, especially when you're working with PHP and/or HTML. Remember that the browser's job is to **RENDER** html, and anything that LOOKS like HTML, including PHP tags. If you get wonky looking output in the browser, ALWAYS do a "view source" to see the raw 'code' of the page - you'll probably see your PHP and html code there, coming through just fine.

Comment: echo accepts multiple command-separated arguments. why force php to concatenate multiple strings when the concatted result is simply going to be thrown away right away anyways?

Comment: Have you ever benchmarked it? Can't believe this is really of any significance.

Comment: for small things like this, it's a minor optimization. but every little bit counts, sometimes. consider the savings if you're outputting two+ very long strings.

Comment: Could use [the highlight function][http://php.net/manual(/en/function.highlight-file.php)

Comment: @MarcB is it possible to see the PHP code in the browser (the client side) ? Because as far as my knowledge goes it is only on the server side.

Comment: what you're doing with file_get_contents is trying to send the raw unexecuted code to the browser. if you're trying to RUN that external code, then you should be using `include()` or `require()`.

Comment: @DarkBee that does what i want, but the highlighting part i want to handle myself..! Thanxx!

Answer (score 0):

Your browser is trying to interpret the file as HTML code, as has been pointed out by Mark B. A clean solution would be to make the browser interpret the response body as plain text, like this :

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/plain');
echo file_get_contents(__FILE__);
exit;
```

Note: In PHP `__FILE__` always refers to the current file.

Comment: And how do I revert back to the normal interpretation by browser by changing the header? Thanks..!